# Help me find the right Stack Exchange site/tag for my question

Tags: support, tags, questions, site-recommendation

This is my first attempt at using Stack Exchange, so please go easy on me if I'm doing the wrong thing here. I need expert advice on choosing the right computer to buy to fulfill a specific need. I'm fairly sure I came across a Stack Exchange post with an appropriate tag while looking for something else months ago, but now I cannot find it on the site or through Google. Unfortunately, I can't remember the exact wording but it had something to do with choosing computers or recommending computers. Does anyone know if this tag really exists and, if so, where I can find it?

Answer (score 6):

The site you may be thinking of is [Super User](http://superuser.com) that covers computer hardware although if you check their [help page](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) you'll see:

> and it is not about …
>
> - asking for a product, service or learning material recommendation

Generally Stack Exchange disallow those sorts of recommendation questions because products on the market are changing all the time and the answers quickly become obsolete. However if you do your own research on systems available and get stuck with specific questions, like the difference between two types of RAM for example that would likely be the best site to ask on.

Answer (score 0):

There’s an Area 51 proposal for such a site:

[**Hardware Recommendations**](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/65287/hardware-recommendations?referrer=E9UyPC567ihg1JcHSmnJDQ2)

> Proposed Q&A site for people seeking specific hardware recommendations, either for home or office.